# How to initialize data using map inside useState in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid, use-state, ag-grid-react

I'm new to React and in the assignment I'm working on, I have to show data in a AG Grid table. For that this is how I'm initializing `rowData` inside `useState()`, but it's not shown in the webpage. The table is empty with just column names.

```
const CommentTable: React.FC<CommentProps> = (props) => {
  const { comments }  = props;//comments is an array of an object named Comment.

  const [rowData] = useState(comments.map(comment => {
    return {
      postName: comment.inputs.postName,
      commentName: comment.name,
      size: getSize(comment)
    }
  }));

  const columnDefs = [
    { field: 'postName', headerName: 'Post Name' },
    { field: 'commentName', headerName: 'Comment Name' },
    { field: 'size', headerName: 'Size'  }
  ]
   }

  return (
    <div style={{height:'5000px', width:'100%'}}>
    <AgGridReact
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      rowData={rowData}
    />
  </div>
)
```

The code inside `useState()` seems to have no issues but I can't understand why no data is being shown in the table on the webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `props.comments` is a populated array on the initial render cycle then mapping it in the `useState` hook for the initial state value should work. If it is ***not*** available on the initial render then you'll use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on `props.comments` to update the `rowData` state when it [`comments`] updates.

```
const { comments } = props;

const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setRowData(comments.map(comment => ({
    postName: comment.inputs.postName,
    commentName: comment.name,
    size: getSize(comment)
  })));
}, [comments]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to split your code. The declaration with a useState() hook and the splitting of the map via a useEffect() hook.

Example:

```js
const CommentTable: React.FC<CommentTableProps> = (props) => {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState();
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState();

  const columnDefs = [
      { field: 'postName', headerName: 'Post Name' },
      { field: 'commentName', headerName: 'Comment Name' },
      { field: 'size', headerName: 'Size'  }
    ]
   }
   
  useEffect(() => {             
    setComments(props);
  }, [props]);
  
  useEffect(() => {   
    comments.foreach((scenario) => {
      let row {
        postName: comment.inputs.postName,
        commentName: comment.name,
        size: getSize(comment)
    })
   setRowData((rowData) => [...rowData, row])
  }, [comments]);
   

  return (
    <div className="a-css-class" style={{height:'5000px', width:'100%'}}>
    <AgGridReact
      modules={AllModules}
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      rowData={rowData}
    />
  </div>
)
```

For more information please visit:

useState() -> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

useEffect() -> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html